# AJAX Session called twice. It doesn't show an alert the second time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I have an AJAX session that gets called once on page load and again after a click. It's not getting a readystate change the second time so I decided to test it by putting an alert box in the function. The alert box shows up on the page load. But on the click it doesn't show up - get this - even though the PHP side executes. More puzzling is that if I try to measure the readystate it never appears (not 0,1,2,3 or 4 - an alert box won't even show up), and I don't get an return text.

What I ultimately am trying to achieve is for the xmlhttp.responseText to return a value like it does on the page load. What am I missing?

JavaScript:

```js
function ajaxSession()
{
alert();
xmlhttp = undefined;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
 z = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}

function stateCheck()
{
ajaxSession();
xmlhttp.open('POST', thisurl + '/favoritecheck.php',false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send("0=" + perform + "&1=" + thisplace + ",&2=" + thisusername);
}


function firstCheck()
{
perform = 0;
stateCheck();
 if (z == 'found')
 {
 document.getElementById("favorite").src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-on.png";
 document.getElementById("favtext").innerHTML="This is a favorite!";
 }
 if ( z == 'nouser')
 {
 perform = 1;
 stateCheck();
 }
}

function heartCheck()
{
perform = 2;
stateCheck();
 if (z == 'added')
 {
 document.getElementById("favorite").src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-on.png";
 document.getElementById("favtext").innerHTML="This is a favorite!";
 }
 if (z == 'subtracted')
 {
 document.getElementById("favorite").src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-off.png";
 document.getElementById("favtext").innerHTML="Add to your favorites.";
 }
}



if (loggedin == 1)
{
document.writeln('<img id="favorite" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="heartCheck()" src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-off.png" alt="Favorite" />'
+ '<br />'
+ '<div id="favtext" style="color: #D20425;">'
+ 'Add to your favorites.'
+ '</div>');
firstCheck();
} else if (loggedin == 0)
{
document.writeln('<img id="favorite" style="cursor: pointer;" src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-off.png" alt="Favorite" />'
+ '<br />'
+ '<div id="favtext" style="color: #D20425;">'
+ '<a style="color: #800000; font-weight: bold;" href="' + thisurl + '/wp-login.php">Log in</a> to add favorites.'
+ '</div>');
}
```

PHP:

```html
<?php

include('connect.php');

$salt = "********";

$perform = $_POST[0];
$place = $_POST[1];
$user = $_POST[2];
$usercrypt = crypt(md5($user),$salt);
$placeid = trim($place,",");

function checkNow()
{
global $usercrypt;
global $place;
global $conn;
$urow = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Users.User FROM Users WHERE Users.User='" . $usercrypt . "';");
 if (mysqli_num_rows($urow) > 0)
 {
 $favcheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Users.Favorites FROM Users WHERE Users.User='" . $usercrypt . "';");
 $favcheck = mysqli_fetch_array($favcheck);
 $favcheck = $favcheck[0];
  if (strpos($favcheck, $place) !== false)
  {
  $answer = 'found';
  }
  else
  {
  $answer = 'notfound';
  }
 }
 else
 {
 $answer = 'nouser';
 }
return array($answer,$favcheck);
unset($answer);
}
 
if ($perform == "0")
{
$sendback = checkNow();
echo $sendback[0];
unset($sendback);
}

if ($perform == "1")
{
global $usercrypt;
global $conn;
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO Users (User) VALUES ('" . $usercrypt . "')");
}

if ($perform == "2")
{
$sendback = checkNow();
global $place;
global $placeid;
global $usercrypt;
global $conn;
$currentnum = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Places.Favorites FROM Places WHERE Places.PlaceID=" . $placeid);
$currentnum = mysqli_fetch_array($currentnum);
$currentnum = $currentnum[0];
 if ($sendback[0] == 'found')
 {
 $currentnum--;
 $change = str_replace($place,'',$sendback[1]);
 mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Users SET Favorites='" . $change . "' WHERE User = '" . $usercrypt . "'");
 mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Places SET Places.Favorites=" . $currentnum . " WHERE Places.PlaceID =" . $placeid);
 $answer = 'subtracted';
 }
 if ($sendback[0] == 'notfound')
 {
 $currentnum++;
 $change = $sendback[1] . $place;
 mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Users SET Favorites='" . $change . "' WHERE User = '" . $usercrypt . "'");
 mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE Places SET Places.Favorites=" . $currentnum . " WHERE Places.PlaceID =" . $placeid);
 $answer = 'added';
 }
return $answer;
unset($answer);
}

unset($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well, please?

Comment: just a note: `unset` after return will not get executed and `global` should be used only inside a function.

Comment: HTML is too long to add to the post. It's a standard WordPress page. This is the content of the page text:

'<?php

include('connect.php');

$place = 63;

include('placelist.php');

?>'

Comment: Where do you declar or set your loggedin var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `z` will be evaluated *before* the xmlhttp object receives the readystate change. You need to put all the code that deals with the returned value into a `onreadystatechange` function itself, since that is the only function which is guaranteed to be called after you receive an asynchronous response.

You could do something like this:

```
var xmlhttp = false;
// The rest of your code, but remove the `onreadystatechange` assignment from ajaxSession()
// ...
// ...
function heartCheck() {
    perform = 2;
    stateCheck();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        z = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (z == 'added')
        {
        document.getElementById("favorite").src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-on.png";
        document.getElementById("favtext").innerHTML="This is a favorite!";
        }
        if (z == 'subtracted')
        {
        document.getElementById("favorite").src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-off.png";
        document.getElementById("favtext").innerHTML="Add to your favorites.";
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd need to do a handler like that for each time you want to evaluate the AJAX response.

It'd also be most clear to declare the global variables at the beginning of the script like I did above--as @jeroen mentions, it's not explicitly required, but it's good practice and will help you keep track of scope. It's confusing that `z` is only defined inside the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function, yet you're using it throughout the script globally. So a simple tip is to put `var z  = ''` at the beginning of your JavaScript to make your intentions clearer (both to yourself and to others who may be viewing your code :))

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. This has been driving me mad for 2 days straight now. I needed it explained the way you did.

Comment: Great answer although personally I'd try to avoid the whole global variable mess :-)

Comment: No problem. Good luck! jeroen's advice is very true: it's best to avoid such structures in the future in order to dodge the confusing spaghetti. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a mess: You are mixing asynchronous and synchronous javascript in a way you will never know what is what and in what state you are in. Apart from that you are using global javascript variables that you reset and overwrite synchronously while you are using them for your asynchronous requests.

Check for example your `firstCheck()` function: That will reset your `xmlhttp` variable (in another function...) and make a asynchronous request but you are already checking for the return value of your asynchronous request in the next line when you are checking the `z` value. That value (another global variable...) will only be set when your asynchronous call finishes so that logic has no place there.

You need to rethink your architecture keeping in mind that each time you make an ajax request, the result will not be available right away, a separate event will fire - a `readyState` change - and only then can you do the things you want to do with the returned information from the server.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the gaping flaws that I just didn't see. I'm self-taught (as evident!) and I really needed some outside perspective.